# How to setup HTTP and HTTPS on the same port with akka-http

Tags: scala, akka-http

I have a Scala app that runs an `akka-http` webserver on a custom port, let's say `8000`.

Until a while ago, it would only handle `http://` requests, but recently I switched to `https://`.

Some of the clients have the link bookmarked and keep getting the no connection error because they try the address with `http://` instead of `https://` and they keep forgetting why it happens.

I tried binding two services to the same port but failed because only the first one gets binded.

```
Http().bind(interface = "0.0.0.0", port = Global.settings.restPort, connectionContext = httpsContext)
Http().bind(interface = "0.0.0.0", port = Global.settings.restPort)
```

All I need from the `http://` server is to return a 301 code and redirect to the same address, but with `https` protocol.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can't bind two TCP sockets to the same port. Usually http is bound to default 80 and https to default 443, with the former redirecting to the latter. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: Why not use Nginx or Apache to direct the HTTP or HTTPS requests to the Akka HTTP server's port? You'd have to get your users to move from using the custom port, but as far as I know using both HTTP and HTTPS on the same port is not possible due to TCP binding.

Answer (score 2):

As others have commented, you can't bind the HTTP and HTTPS servers to the same port.  You can have both servers running on separate ports and redirect all HTTP traffic to the HTTPS server using Akka-http's `scheme()` and `redirect()`:

```
val hostName = "www.example.com"
val portHttp = 8080
val portHttps = 8443

val route =
  scheme("http") {
    extract(_.request.uri) { uri =>
      redirect( uri.withScheme("https").withAuthority(hostName, portHttps),
        StatusCodes.MovedPermanently
      )
    }
  } ~
  pathSingleSlash {
    get {
      complete( HttpEntity( ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`,
        "Welcome to Akka-HTTP!"
      ) )
    }
  }

Http().bindAndHandle(route, hostName, portHttp)
Http().bindAndHandle(route, hostName, portHttps, connectionContext = httpsContext)
```

Note that there is no need for applying `withAuthority()` if you're using standard HTTP and HTTPS ports (i.e. 80 and 443).

Comment: Can't I bind only one server to handle both http and https requests on the same port?

Comment: Just realized I might've misunderstood your comment question.  As stated earlier, you can't have both HTTP and HTTPS services listen to the same port.  HTTPS uses SSL/TLS protocol which for security reason can't be simply downgraded to HTTP upon detecting unencrypted communication.